# What is the bug in this WeakEventHandler?

Tags: c#, clr

If found WeakEventHandler in [this blog post](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/06/06/weakeventhandler)

But he says:

Update: Yes, I know this is broken. There's a bug that means it doesn't work...

and does not says what is the bug :(

```
public class WeakEventHandler<DT, T> where T : EventArgs
{
    private WeakReference weakRefToOriginalDelegate;
    public WeakEventHandler(EventHandler<T> originalDelegate)
    {
        weakRefToOriginalDelegate = new WeakReference(originalDelegate);
    }

    private void DoInvoke(object sender, T args)
    {
        EventHandler<T> originalDelegate = (EventHandler<T>) weakRefToOriginalDelegate.Target;
        if (originalDelegate != null) originalDelegate(sender, args);
    }

    public static implicit operator DT(WeakEventHandler<DT, T> wd)
    {
        object o = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (DT), wd, "DoInvoke");
        return (DT) o;
    }
}
```

Could someone explain what is the bug in this WeakEventHandler implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Jeffrey Richter, author of "CLR via C#" actually covered `WeakEventHandler` and `WeakDelegate` implementations in CLR via C#.

There is no point repeating it here for you, but you can view his revised code here: https://www.wintellect.com/weak-event-handlers/

The code shown in the book doesn't quite work as he intended, so the above link points to his corrections.

Comment: I'm not looking for implementation of weak event, but rather want to understand what is the problem with implementation I showed above. I've just checked CLR via C#, it has about the same weak event handler implementation as I showed above. Richter says in his blog that it does not work as intended, so I want to know what is the problem with this implementation.

Comment: I see the difference is the first version uses WeakReference to reference delegate itself, but "corrected version" uses WeakReference to reference target of the delegate. What does it mean? WeakReference does not work correctly when references delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Do garbage collection before the first call to the delegate, and you'll find that the code doesn't work as expected,Because the delegate object is reclaimed ahead of time by the garbage collector

```
    ..Code snippet.............
    EventHandler h = new WeakEventHandler<EventHandler, EventArgs>(p.Handler);
    GC.Collect();
    h(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    p = null;
    ...............
```

In addition
You can refer to the example in CLR via C# 3, section 21, section 12, but my test found that it was still not working properly. I tried to modify the code as follows and found that it worked as expected

```
    ..Code snippet.............
    public DotNotLiveJustForEvent()
    {
        ClickedHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(Clicked);
    }

    //Add a member variable that references the Clicked method
    public RoutedEventHandler ClickedHandler = null;
    public void Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
    }
    ...............
    ..Code snippet.............
        //The input parameter is changed to the variable
        btnTest.Click+= new WeakEventHandler(new DotNotLiveJustForEvent().ClickedHandler) {
            RemoveDelegateCode = eh =>
            {
               // btnTest.Click -= eh;
            }
        };
   ...............
```

Note: I'm not sure this is correct, as I don't know how the interior works, just for reference